# There is no folder "library/keyboard" on my MacBook Air

Tags: macos

I need to install Lao keyboard files in the folder `library/keyboard`.

When I click on `library/keyboard` I get a message saying the folder can't be found.  How do I remedy this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` [according to the manual](http://www.laoscript.net/support/Mac%20OS%20X/Installing%20Lao%20keyboard%20and%20fonts%20on%20Mac%20OS%20X.php).

Simply open Finder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and paste `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` in the input field. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Put your files in the newly opened folder.